# Grouping QuerySet in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Having scheme like this:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    pass


class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    date = models.DateField()


class Model3(models.Model):
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2)
```

I need to query `Model3` having unique `model2__model1__id` and the least `model2__date`.
I've managed to make required query using `QuerySet.extra()` method, like this:

```
Model3.objects.order_by('model2__date').extra(select={'m1_id': 'DISTINCT `app_model2`.`model1_id`'})
```

But I'm afraid it won't work with additional sortings etc.
I also don't want to use raw queries as those don't support sorting as well, and also database-level slicing (there could be huge amounts of records).

Is there more correct way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

**UP:**
I am using MySQL DB backend, so `distinct()` with field names is not available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution: module [django-group-by](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-group-by) allows to apply grouping to querysets, like this:

```
Model3.objects.group_by('model2__model1')
```

(You need to mix `GroupByMixin` into the model manager)

Answer (score 1):

I know you can do the following

```
Model3.objects.order_by('model2__model1_id', 'model2__date').distinct('model2__model1_id')
```

Unfortunately it's not sorted by `model2.date`, but for each `model1.id` the `model2.date` is the least, and it's sorted by model1 id

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to mention that I can't use PostgreSQL, so `distinct(*field_names)` is unavailable.

Comment: I guess adding the extra as you are doing might be the way to go then.